# Vokoscreen VP9 Codec in Debian 10 Buster

Tags: video, debian, codec, vp9

Kdenlive for Debian Buster allows me to render using the VP8 and VP9 codecs.  Also, I *think* Vokoscreen 3.0.8 for Win 10 allows me to record using VP9.  Unfortunately, when I install Vokoscreen 2.5.0 in Debian Buster, I don't see an option for Google VP9 Codec (See Picture):

[image]

What is the easiest way for me to get Google VP9 video compression inside Vokoscreen on Debian 10?

Comment: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good is already installed and at the latest version from what I can tell.  See also:
https://github.com/vkohaupt/vokoscreenNG

Comment: I installed backport vokoscreen-ng (3.0.7-1~bpo10+1) on a Debian 10 machine and I at least get Google/On2 VP8 support now. I guess Vokoscreen 2.5.0 was just really old...

Comment: The VokoscreenNG 3.0.7 that comes by default on Debian 11 also has Google/On2 VP8 support which is "good enough" for me...  No need to use a backport on Debian 11.